# Linear transformation Df=$\frac{df}{dx}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $Rx$ define vector space of all real polynomials. Let $D:Rx \to  Rx$ denote map  Df=$\frac{df}{dx}$, for every f. Then which of following is true.

1. $D$ is one-to-one
2. $D$ is onto
3. There exist $E:Rx \to  Rx$ such that $D(E(f))=f$, for every $f$
4. There exist $E:Rx \to  Rx$ such that $E(D(f))=f$, for every $f$

My attempt: I think $D$ is not one-to-one because two polynomials can have the same derivative. This implies $D$ is is not invertible also therefore option 3 and 4 become false also. But I don't know about onto. Is my solution right so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not completely. $D$ is not invertible, so $E(D(p)) \ne \mathrm{Id}$ but the other way around is actually possible (this is because $\mathbb R[x]$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space). The operator $E$ can be defined by
$$Ef(x) := \int_0^x f(t)\mathrm dt$$
Then $DEf = f\ \forall f\in\mathbb{R}[x]$. Your other observations are correct, though.
Now since $DE = \mathrm{Id}$, we already know that $D$ must be surjective.
As a plus we get since $D$ isn't injective, $E$ can't be surjective.

Comment: Some things are unclear id DE = id then how it Implies D is onto? And why D is invertible when it is not one on, I.e why E(Df)=id but not other way

Comment: @Foggy If a composition is onto, so must be the outermost operator ($D(E(\mathbb R[x])) = \mathbb R[x] \Rightarrow D(\mathbb R[x]) = \mathbb R[x]$). $D$ is only right-invertible. In finite dimensional vector spaces, right-invertibility is equivalent to left-invertibility. If $AB = I$ then $BA=I$ and $B$ is a two-sided inverse of $A$. In infinite dimensions, this is no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

2. Yes. Let $I(f)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$, $g=I(f)$ always exists and $D(g)=f$.
3. Yes. $E$ can be the $I$ just defined.
4. No. $D$ drops the constant term irreversibly.