# Check whether partial derivative commutes with inverse partial derivative.

Tags: partial-derivative

Is the following true? with proof. In other words check whether $\partial^{2}_{r}$ commutes with $\partial^{-2}_{r}$. 
$$\partial^{-2}_{r}\partial^{2}_{r}=\partial^{2}_{r}\partial^{-2}_{r}$$
Side Note: In case of $\Box^{-1}\Box\neq \Box\Box^{-1}$.

Comment: $\Box$ is the d'Alembert operator?

Comment: Yes it is AlexR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
Check out the most basic case: One variable and the space $\mathbb R[x]$.
Is
$$\frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dx^2} \int_0^x \int_0^s f(t) \mathrm dt \ \mathrm ds = \int_0^x \int_0^s \frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dt^2} f(t) \mathrm dt \mathrm ds \qquad?$$
This question is answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1126387/linear-transformation-df-fracdfdx/1126395?noredirect=1) (not really a duplicate, but will answer your question as well)

Comment: thanks AlexR, they indeed are not equal. the RHS in zero while the LHS is non zero!

Comment: @Ilia _can be_ zero... If you have $\deg f > 2$ and the quadratic, linear and constant terms zero, the equality actually works ^^

Comment: yet how do you define the same integral for the particular case above? is this also true for above?

Comment: @Ilia Yes, it is. If the 1D case fails already you can pick $\phi(r,\theta) = f(r)$ with a counter-example function $f$ to pull it up into higher dimensions.

Comment: Great thanks :)

Comment: Yes, it works rarely, let alone in general. After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Comment: Just did :) a bit new to this website...

Comment: No problem :) We all were at some point. The [help center](/help) is a good place to start exploring.

Comment: Now another question I have in mind is what is happening in the following cases? $$[\Box,\frac{1}{\Box}]\mathcal{O}=0 ? $$ $$[\nabla,\frac{1}{\nabla}]\mathcal{O}=0 ? $$ $$[\nabla^2,\frac{1}{\nabla^2}]\mathcal{O}=0 ? $$ $$[\partial^{2}_{r},\frac{1}{\partial^{2}_{r}}]\mathcal{O}=0 ?$$ in the case of $\Box$ we know they do not commute.. and $\mathcal{O}$ is operator.

Comment: You should ask that as a new question, showing also how you came to this and what your thoughts are to ensure the best possible answers-